# How to create php code inside onClick()

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is it possible to do something like this

```
 <td onclick="<?php $_SESSION['key']=$value; ?>"> </td>
```

If it is not possible, how to do something similar?

Comment: What do you expect? You assign the value of a variable to another. No echo, no output.

Comment: You could do `<td onclick="function_name('<?php echo $value; ?>')"> </td>`;

Comment: You can't run PHP code on client side events without some sort of AJAX request or form submit.

Comment: I want to add the value to the session when clicking the td, I have no idea how to do that, any help appreciated.

Comment: See the second comment it answer you. Else you can do an ajax request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to execute directly php code in javascript function for a simple reason : Php is executed on the server side, and javascript is executed on the client side (so, after the php execution).

If you want to execute some php with a click, you have two options :
put a link on you td, which send you on the php script or use an ajax function executed by a click on your element.